# Getting error while sending mail to recpient

Tags: gmail, email-bounces

Can anyone help me with this error, what is wrong with this.

Feb 20 08:03:15 free postfix_217.23.10.180/smtp[7218]: B8BEB487CC8F: to=, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.133.27]:25, delay=0.24, delays=0.04/0/0.03/0.17, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.133.27] said: 550-5.7.1 [217.23.10.180      12] Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit 550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information. t203si19652491wmf.55 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems like you are trying to send mail via Gmails SMTP server, but it says your mail looks like spam. Unless you show some code, I think that this question will eventually be closed. Please see the FAQ.

Comment: Can u help me with this  550-5.7.1 error code. Thanks in advance

Comment: After reading [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/K5klFKDnUAE), I found [these guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126) that might apply to you. Good luck.